# getting errors :java.lang.IllegalArgumentException and unlockCanvasAndPost

Tags: android, android-intent, android-canvas

I am drawing bitmaps on canvas. Everything is working fine when I use the device which I have. But when I use other device application crashes.
This happens when I move from `myView` activity to sign activity.. I don't know what's the matter. I searched it a lot but could'nt find the suitable solution.


Getting these errors in logcat

```
11-26 06:54:37.844: E/FRAG(21746): onActivityCreated called
11-26 06:54:38.305: E/AndroidRuntime(21746): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1476
11-26 06:54:38.305: E/AndroidRuntime(21746): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
11-26 06:54:38.305: E/AndroidRuntime(21746):    at android.view.Surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(Native Method)
11-26 06:54:38.305: E/AndroidRuntime(21746):    at android.view.SurfaceView$4.unlockCanvasAndPost(SurfaceView.java:775)
11-26 06:54:38.305: E/AndroidRuntime(21746):    at com.example.watermarks.MyThread.run(Panel.java:541)
```

In myView.class I passing intent on wtermarks button

    
    waterMarks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    
                    Intent i = new Intent(myView.this, Signs.class);
                    byteArrayCapPic=Utilities.getBytes(mView.returnCanvasBtmp());
                    i.putExtra("picture", byteArrayCapPic);
                    //mView.stopThread();
                    startActivity(i);
    
                }
            });

`MyThread` class

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
    Panel panel;
    private SurfaceHolder myHolder;
    boolean mRun = false;

    public MyThread(Panel panel) {
        this.panel = panel;
        this.myHolder = panel.getHolder();
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        this.mRun = run;
    }

    public void run() {
        Canvas canvas = null;
        while (mRun) {
            canvas = myHolder.lockCanvas();
            if (canvas != null) {
                // mythread.join();
                panel.Draw(canvas);
            }
            myHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            //this.myHolder.lockCanvas();
        }
        //this.myHolder.lockCanvas();
    }
}
```

Comment: please paste your full logcat

Comment: Their are infinite messages in logcat which i cant post.I am able to post only errors.

Comment: if you want to see whole code that i can post

Comment: Is the Canvas you are passing to `myHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost` null when it fails? The error says its an illegal argument in that call.

Comment: But run fine on device which i am using

Comment: Thanks Dave.canvas was null when i was moving towards another activity.But i don't why it was working fine on one device